# Knowledge smart link insertion fails redirection abstract record to concrete knowledge record

Tags: knowledge, smart-link

Looks like there is some internal Salesforce bug about smart link insertion into Knowledge Article.

When a new article is created and Smart Link to another Knowledge Article is inserted into Rich Text Area field, the link which is displayed doesn't work fine.

There is abstract link which is not transformed into concrete object link.

Is this a known salesforce issue? Are there any workarounds for this?

This is interesting that if we refresh the link manually, it works. Also it works the second time when user clicks the link.